# How to solve this age problem?

Tags: problem-solving

I am solving the following question. Please guide me!!

The ages of A and B are in the ratio of 5:7 and C and D are in the ratio of 5:7.Let sum of their ages is 150, what is the difference between the ages of A and D?

My Solution:

$A/B= 5/7$ , Thus $B=7A/5$

$C/D= 5/7$ , Thus $C=5D/7$

As sum is 150, we can write

$A + B + C + D= 150$

$A + (7A/5) + (5D/7) + D = 150$

$(12A/5) + (12D/7) =150$

$A/5 + D/7 = 150/12$

$A/5 + D/7 = 12.5$

Now how to find difference between ages of A and D now? 
Is my way of solving question wrong.

Thankyou in advance

Comment: You are correct and, as you noticed, you miss one piece of information to answer.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici.. What did I miss?

Comment: Any extra information which would relate $A$ to $D$. Suppose that you $A \times D$ or $A+D$ this will give you a second equation and, by elimination, you will get a single equation in $A$ or $D$.

Comment: okay! :( Thankyou sir!!

Comment: You are very welcome ! Cheers :-)

Comment: are you sure your question said C and D and not B and C?

Comment: yes.. I have now confirmed it as well.. No additional info was given!

Answer (score 2):

If we assume the ages of A and B to be 5x and 7x, respectively, and those of C and D to be 5y and 7y, respectively, we get

12x + 12y = 150 
which gives 
x + y = 12.5

Now, unless x and y are equal, which we can't assume, it's not possible to find the difference between ages of A and D. (5x and 7y)

So, to summarise, you have one equation and two unknown parameters. It's not possible to deduce them uniquely.

Comment: okay!! so, it is not possible to solve this question..